# Two Dimensional Vector push_back

Tags: c++, vector

I have a two dimensional vector A made up of other vectors B

```
vector < vector < int >> A

vector < int > B
```

I use the `push_back` function to populate B.

```
B.push_back(1);
B.push_back(2);
B.push_back(3);
```

After that vector is populated, I use `push_back` again to populate A with B

```
A.push_back(B)
```

This is done several times so that A eventually results in a vector containing several other vectors looking like:

```
A { {1 , 2 , 3 }, { 2, 2, 2 }, {8, 9, 10} }
```

How can I make a call to a specific index in A and then continue to add to the vector so that the output would be similar to

```
A { {1 , 2 , 3 }, { 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6 }, {8, 9, 10} }
```

Something along the lines of

```
A[2].push_back(4);
A[2].push_back(5);
A[2].push_back(6);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you have is correct except that indexes start at `0`, so it should be `A[1].push_back(4);` and not `2`.

Comment: @BarryTormey: Could you post the full example? [Here is an example of your code](http://ideone.com/ZNdEwN) that works fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
A[2].push_back(4);
A[2].push_back(5);
A[2].push_back(6);
```

Should work perfectly fine. Except if you want the second element then you'll need to use a[1] as vectors are 0 based.